# Are there any problems whose best known algorithms have running time $n^{\log \log n}$?

Tags: complexity-classes, time-complexity

It’s well known that problems such as integer factorization have running times contained in $e^{\text{Poly} \log }$ which is the same $n^{ \text{Poly} \log }$ (actually the log term is itself in a cube root for integer factorization)

So this got me wondering about complexity classes that live between polynomial time and $e^{\text{Poly} \log }$ namely $e^{\log \cdot \text{Poly} \log \log }$ or $n^{\text{Poly} \log \log}$ as the title puts it.

Are there any problems whose best known algorithms live in this runtime complexity?

Comment: Integer factorization is most certainly not known to have quasipolynomial-time ($n^{(\log n)^c}$) algorithms. This would break a lot of public key cryptography, for a start. The best known factoring algorithms are exponential-time ($2^{n^\epsilon}$, for $\epsilon\approx1/3$; some people falsely advertize this as “subexponential”).

Comment: My apologies I made the mistake of n in my polylog statement being the number and not the input size

Comment: See the notation here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization#Difficulty-and-complexity in section “current state of the art”

Comment: Yes, the wikipedia article misleadingly uses $n$ for the number itself rather than the length of the input.

Comment: What about how many primes numbers there up to n^(log(log(n))?

Answer (score 11):

The best-known deterministic algorithm for testing polynomial identities given by depth-three diagonal circuits has running time $n^{O(\log \log n)}$ [1].

More explicitly, we are given an expression of the form $$f(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = \sum_{i=1}^s (a_{i,0} + a_{i,1} x_1 + \cdots + a_{i,n} x_n)^{d_i}$$ and we want to test if $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ is the identically zero polynomial. Forbes, Shpilka, and Saptharishi gave a deterministic algorithm for this problem that runs in time $\mathsf{poly}(n,d,s)^{O(\log \log (ds))}$, where $d = \max_{i\in [s]}d_i$. Of course, it is conjectured that polynomial identity testing can be solved in deterministic polynomial time, so this is unlikely to be the best possible deterministic algorithm for this problem.

[1] *Forbes, Michael A.; Saptharishi, Ramprasad; Shpilka, Amir*, [**Hitting sets for multilinear read-once algebraic branching programs, in any order**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/2591796.2591816), Proceedings of the 46th annual ACM symposium on theory of computing, STOC ’14, New York, NY, USA, May 31 – June 3, 2014. New York, NY: Association for Computing Machinery (ACM) (ISBN 978-1-4503-2710-7). 867-875 (2014). [ZBL1315.68127](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1315.68127).

Answer (score 9):

The best-known algorithm for testing isomorphism of finite groups whose solvable radical is either (a) contained in the center or (b) elementary abelian, is $n^{O(\log \log n)}$. These are, respectively, Theorems A and B of my [paper with Youming Qiao](https://doi.org/10.1137/15M1009767). In this case, the bound comes from enumerating the automorphisms of $G/Rad(G)$, which is a group with no abelian normal subgroups (aka Fitting-free or semisimple). The number of such automorphisms can indeed be as large as $n^{\Theta(\log \log n)}$ (e.g. if $G/Rad(G) \cong A_5^k$ where $k = \Theta(\log |G|)$). Improving this upper bound to $n^{o(\log \log n)}$ thus requires a new strategy (my guess would be that it's doable though).

Answer (score 1):

Probably not as interesting or natural such as the problems mentioned in the previous answers, another problem that would fit in your question in the one of finding a clique of size $\log\log n$ in a graph with $n$ vertices. And I believe that, under some standard [parameterized complexity assumptions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem#Fixed-parameter_intractability), this cannot be improved.

Comment: This answer is not incorrect, but to me choosing a parameter in a parameterized problem (here, the clique size) to get the time bound you want feels like cheating.

Comment: For sure! That's why I said it was not that natural. But perhaps it is still useful for the OP.